# New install of ubuntu server, and networking is not working correctly with Intel 82579LM

Tags: networking, netplan

So I have a Dell Optiplex 790 with a Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit NIC. So first problem I encountered is during installer, it said autoconfiguration failed, so I installed without networking. Once booted, network was unconfigured, so I edited /etc/netplan/* and tried to enable dhcp, but it wouldn't get an address. So I then set address to be static, and can access the network now, but not well. For example if I ping from another machine, I get replies to ever other one, and and ssh is very laggy from within the network. Does anyone know what might be wrong, or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Looked around for a solution, both the installer and the live cd (trial) do not detect the network card (no networking available).

`lshw -c network`

will show the network hardware is detected but "unclaimed". Not sure what that means. Unhelpfully, most of the fixes tell you to run stuff that requires downloading pkgs ie. over the network. Sheesh.

I ended up plugging in another network card (rtl8111) to get networking going.

`ubuntu version 20.04, live cd - no patches applied.`